# Mac OS X Server with multiple iOS simulator

Tags: xamarin, osx-services

We are working in a small team making Xamarin apps in Android and iOS. We want increase the team and we are looking for the best way in order to minimice the hardware cost.

Our first option is buy as many macs as employees.

The second one is buy a mac pro and set up as Mac server with Mac OS X server.

My problem is, that I don't know if it's possible, running multiple iOS simulator with multiple user using screen sharing from windows pc.

Or, exists other best option?

Comment: Buy a mac for each developer. Consider MacBooks so they can work from home if necessary.

Comment: 1 way would be to setup multiple VM's in the server for each user.its seems its impossible to run multiple simulators.

Comment: @Exlord I find a way to run multiple simulators in the same mac. I tested and works.[irapp launcher](http://www.coderebel.com/products/ios-simulator-launcher/)